# Check if string exists inside a json foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to check if a value exists inside an foreach loop from a decoded json response and compare it to my own string. I need to set $response_array['status'] to "Allowed" if $domain_to_check value exists inside the $key_info['registered_domain'] array. I tried to use in_array php function to check if value exists, however i had no success and i keep getting back "Not Allowed - Domain not listed" response even when the value is inside the array. I think that the problem is with my foreach loop but for the sake of me i can't figure whats wrong.

```
$domain_to_check = 'domain-name.com';
$data = json_decode($returnCheckValue,true);
$key_response = $data['result'];
if ($key_response == 'success'){
    foreach ($data['registered_domains'] as $key_domain_info) {
        $key_listed_domain = $key_domain_info['registered_domain'];
        if ($key_response == 'success' && in_array($domain_to_check, $key_listed_domain)) {
            $response_array['status'] = 'Allowed';
        }
        else {
            $response_array['status'] = 'Not Allowed - Domain not listed';
        }
    }
}
else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'Not Allowed - Wrong Key';
}
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Here is how my var_dump(); of the $data looks like

```
array(9) { ["result"]=> string(7) "success" ["max_allowed_domains"]=> string(1) "3" ["registered_domains"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "60" ["lic_key_id"]=> string(2) "51" ["lic_key"]=> string(13) "93248cqkdj21as" ["registered_domain"]=> string(19) "domain-name-2.com" ["item_reference"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "58" ["lic_key_id"]=> string(2) "51" ["lic_key"]=> string(13) "93248cqkdj21as" ["registered_domain"]=> string(14) "domain-name.com" ["item_reference"]=> string(3) "443" } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relate below code with your code. This code is working.

```
    $domain_to_check = "domain-name.com";

    $test = array("registered_domains" => array("registered_domain" => "domain-name-2.com"), array("registered_domain" => "domain-name.com"));

    foreach($test as $val) {
        if($val['registered_domain'] == $domain_to_check) {
            $result = 'success';
            break;

        } else {
            $result = 'failure';
        }
    }

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i managed to make it work with help of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use php [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$domainStringFound = strpos($key_listed_domain, $domain_to_check);

if ($key_response == 'success' && $domainStringFound !== false) {
  $response_array['status'] = 'Allowed';
}
```

Comment: I updated my code as you suggested, however i get back the same result which is Not Allowed - Domain not listed, although the $domain_to_check value is inside $key_listed_domain array